# Issues implementing collision in Snake game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to implement a loop that checks if the head of the snake (represented by the head of a list snake_parts) is colliding with any part of the snake's body, which are rect objects that compose the rest of the list. But as soon as the snake's body extends, there is constant collision between the two objects. Given how the body of the snake is implemented, I can't see how they'd ever intersect so I'm not sure what's causing the collisions.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import sys


pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIN_WIDTH = 680 #width of window
WIN_HEIGHT = 500 #height of window

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT) #variable for screen display
DEPTH = 32 #standard
FLAGS = 0 #standard
BLACK = (0, 0, 0) #black
RED = (255, 0, 0) #red
GOLD = (255, 215, 0)
LOL = (14, 18, 194)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
pygame.display.set_caption('Snaek')                                      

snake_parts = [1]
Score = 0
speed = 10
snakex = 125
snakey = 70
size = 20


# --- classes ---
class Snake(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, x, y, screen, size, colour):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self, x, y, size, 20)
        self.screen = screen
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.colour, self)

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.x, self.y

class Food(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self, x, y, 20, 20)
        self.screen = screen

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, GOLD, self)

class Barrier(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self, x, y, 40, 20)
        self.screen = screen 
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, LOL, self)


# --- functions ---
def get_food_pos(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT):
    WIN_WIDTH = random.randint(100, WIN_WIDTH-150)
    WIN_HEIGHT = random.randint(100, WIN_HEIGHT-150)
    return WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT

eaten = True
pressed_right = True
pressed_left = False
pressed_up = False
pressed_down = False
pygame.key.set_repeat(10,10)

level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP", 
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
]


while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:          # check for key presses          
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if pressed_right:
                    pressed_right = True# left arrow turns left
                else:
                    pressed_left = True
                    pressed_right = False
                    pressed_up = False
                    pressed_down = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if pressed_left:
                    pressed_left = True# right arrow turns right
                else: 
                    pressed_right = True
                    pressed_left = False
                    pressed_up = False
                    pressed_down = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if pressed_down:# up arrow goes up
                    pressed_down = True
                else:
                    pressed_up = True
                    pressed_right = False
                    pressed_left = False
                    pressed_down = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if pressed_up:
                    pressed_up = False
                else:
                    pressed_down = True
                    pressed_right = False
                    pressed_up = False
                    pressed_left = False

    x = snakex
    y = snakey




    if pressed_left:
        snakex -= speed
    elif pressed_right:
        snakex += speed
    elif pressed_up:
        snakey -= speed
    elif pressed_down:
        snakey += speed

    snake_parts[0] = Snake(snakex, snakey, screen, int(size), RED)
    snake_parts[0].draw(screen)



    if eaten:
        foodx, foody = get_food_pos(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
        eaten = False

    my_food = Food(foodx, foody, screen)
    my_food.draw(screen)

    if snake_parts[0].colliderect(my_food):
        eaten = True
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        a_snake = Snake(snakex, snakey, screen, int(size), RED)
        snake_parts.append(a_snake)


    for i in range(1, len(snake_parts)):
        tempx, tempy = snake_parts[i].coordinates()
        snake_parts[i] = Snake(x, y, screen, int(size), RED)
        if snake_parts[0].colliderect(snake_parts[i]):
            print("Self collision")
        snake_parts[i].draw(screen)
        x, y = tempx, tempy



    platform_x = 0
    platform_y = 0

    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                col = Barrier(platform_x, platform_y, screen)
                col.draw(screen)
                if snake_parts[0].colliderect(col):
                    print("Barrier collision")

            platform_x += 15
        platform_y += 20
        platform_x = 0        



    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: If I read the rules correctly you are not supposed to dump the entire program, but more the *relevant* parts in order to ask for help.

Comment: I've run your program and it does look like you've got this issue with collisions.

Comment: We're not here to debug your entire program to find your problem. You need to know what it is you need help with. If you don't know what's causing the problem you have to break down your program until you've found a reasonable small amount of code that's causing the error. Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/6486738) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/6486738) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging programs like this is very hard, and as @WillemVanOnsem said, we can't quickly understand your code. But based on what I've seen I can give you a few tips to rewrite your game a more robust way:

1. Your board segments could live in 2-dimensional array. Your snake could be represented as a list of **coordinates** in this 2-dimensional array. You could detect collisions **at the moment** of making a move, i.e. when you're about to pop the last element of the snake list and append the next element to the front of the list. I'm pretty sure I've successfully used this method a few years ago to write a minimal game of snake in less than 30 lines of code.
2. Do some unit testing. Put your snake programmatically in a certain position you know leads to unexpected collision and try to understand what's going on. If the problem doesn't become clear then, just ask again.